Battery Management System review
I am posting a schematic design of Battery Management System can someone help me or tell me in finding whether this design is correct or not and will it work

Welcome! Define correct and work. What should it do? What are the limits?

Is it designed for a particular battery technology?

It is guaranteed to collect dust until you define what it does and how you think it works.
